# in SciTE, how to make the whole block of code have less margin in python

Tags: python, scite

My English just as my programming, are not good, apologize.

I'm using SciTE to run python code. I added a `while` statement to the outside of a block of code. Then, in order to indent the next block of code, I selected it and pressed <kbd>tab</kbd>.

After some more coding, I now want to delete the `while` statement and dedent (unindent) the block of code that's in the while-loop. How can I dedent a block of code?

Hope people can understand my poor description, man.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try highlighting the block and hitting shift+tab? Usually is the inverse of tab but I haven't used that editor.

Comment: The usual terms for what you're trying to do are "unindent" or "dedent".

Comment: Thanks very much, it works! Sometimes, there's some error in my code, but I want to know if I could step through the run in SciTE like using Virtue Studio to run C++, so I can know in which step it's wrong, like moving through line by line? Also, could I know the value of each variable? Any other good softwares running python like that?

Comment: For those features I like Eclipse with the pydev plugin. Otherwise I usually stick to a normal text editor, which one depending on my platform at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the block of code and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>